# Perl regex for 8 digit hexadecimal number (may be missing escape characters)

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following code that looks for a folder whose name is a 8 digit hexadecimal number

```
use strict;
use warnings;

opendir(DIR, ".\\");
my @files = readdir(DIR);
closedir DIR;
foreach my $key (@files)
{
    if(-d ".\\$key")
    {
        if ($key =~ /(^[0-9A-F]{8}?$)/){
            print "$1\n";
        }
    }
}
```

i tested the regex on regex101 and it is finding the correct strings (8 digit hex) but the code can't find any of the folders i have that have 8 digit hex as name.  I suspect it has something to do with certain characters needing to be escaped e.g. $ but i tried many different combinations without success.

e.g. a folder's name i have is 906f3387

Comment: try printing $key to see if it is what you expect

Comment: also, the ? isn't needed because you've anchored with $

Comment: Yes, that prints all the folders in the directory, as expected

Comment: @user3669539 Mind listing one of them in the answer or comments?

Comment: @Hunter an example is 906f3387

Comment: also ( and ) aren't needed - try /^[0-9a-zA-Z]{8}$/

Comment: @Les but i need the () to print the folder name, actually i want to rename the folder

Comment: Your example has a lower case letter. Your regex does not.

Comment: @user3669539 - okay, or you could print $key

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your regex is using upper case A-F, but your folder has lower case.  Use `/^[0-9a-fA-F]{8}$/` to explicitly allow lower case, or `/^[0-9A-F]{8}$/i` to ignore case in the match.